# image in NextGen Gallery is showing on new tab

Tags: wordpress

I'm using nextgen gallery plugin to show image on my site. The images lists are showing pretty good in my page but whenever i click on the image it opens in new tab instead of fancybox.
I've tried using fancybox and also light box as Lightbox effect but none are working good.
Any help will greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
For detail here is my site's url. http://www.ace-holidays.com/trips/everest-base-camp-trek/   please checkout the Photos and Videos tab here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom build theme?

There is an error in one of your JavaScript files: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined scripts.js?ver=1.0:316*, this can block the execution of other JavaScript code, like the Fancybox.

If solving that error doesn't work, try using one of the default WordPress themes and check if it works in one of them. Also, make sure your theme is using *wp_head();* and *wp_footer();*.